# Trying to open a unknown file from command line argument, but cant open for some reason

Tags: c, file

Trying to open a `.txt` file from command line arguments, `./a.out courses.txt data.txt`, in a user-defined function, but the files just will not be read. I did get a couple of segmentation faults when I tried to close the files but they went away after I took out the `fclose` functions. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. NOTE: I am a first-year student so I don't know much about code or how to properly ask on here, I apologize beforehand.

Main.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

   #include "givenA3.h"

   int main (int argc, char **argv)
   {

       int userInput;
       int x = 0;
       char *filename [50];
       char courseNames[NUMBER_COURSES][50];
       char profNames[NUMBER_PROFS][30];
       int courseID[NUMBER_COURSES];
       char data[NUMBER_PROFS][NUMBER_COURSES];
       int n = 0;
   
       *filename = argv[1];   // Sets filename to 1st argument.
       readCourseProfData (filename [50], courseNames, profNames, &courseID[NUMBER_COURSES]);
   
       *filename = argv[2];    // Sets filename to 2nd arguemtn.
       readData (filename [50], data);
   }
```

A3.c:

```
    void readCourseProfData (char filename [50], char courseNames[NUMBER_COURSES][50], char            
    profNames[NUMBER_PROFS][30], int courseID[NUMBER_COURSES])
    {

    int lines = 100;
    char buff [lines];
    int i;

    FILE* inFile;
    inFile = fopen(filename, "r");   // Opens file from 2nd argument vector and reads it

    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Can not read courses.txt\n");
    }

    else
    {
        while (fgets(buff, lines, inFile))    // Reads line by line
        {
            for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_COURSES; i++)    // Adds values to array
            {
                sscanf(buff, "%s[^\t\n]", courseNames [i]);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_PROFS; i++)    // Adds values to array
            {
                sscanf(buff, "%s", profNames [i]);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_COURSES; i++)    // Adda values to array
            {
                sscanf(buff, "%d", &courseID [i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tag your question with a programming language so people following that tag can see it.

Comment: `readCourseProfData (filename, ...`? What is the `[50]`? Same for `readData (filename, ...`

Comment: `*filename = argv[1];` This is equivalent to `filename[0] = argv[1];`. But then you pass `filename[50]` to `readCourseProfData` which is both wrong and out of bounds. Are you sure you wanted `filename` to be an array of 50 *pointers* to char, which is what `char *filename [50];` means?

Comment: Also, you cannot call `sscanf(buff, "%s[^\t\n]", courseNames [i]);` inside a loop -- you read the same value. You need to compute `sscanf (buf + offset, ....` Next `[^\t\n]` is not doing what you think it is. *whitespace* in the `sscanf()` format string tells `sscanf` to ingore any number of whitespace characters, but since no conversion specifier follows, no whitespace is ignored. See [man 3 sscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) under the heading `"A directive is one of the following:"` (note the order of what makes up a directive)

Comment: You want to declare `char *filename;` then you can assign `filename = argv[1];`. But before you assign any arguments, you need to check `if (argc < 3) { /* handle error */; return 1; }`. Otherwise if fewer than the required number of arguments are given things will go bad -- quickly.